# How did a user bypass the review queue limit?

Tags: bug, review-queues

I was checking the stats of the [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) review queue earlier, and I noticed that one user has 21 reviews for the day. I was under the impression that there was a hard cap at 20 per day, for all users.

Is this simply a bug allowed this user to slip through?

[image]

I'm not placing any blame on this individual as it is obviously not malicious, I'm just curious.

Comment: after exceeding the queue limit, they could have approved (or rejected) an out-of-queue edit to one of their own posts

Comment: @MartinSmith [how about this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10746295)?

Comment: @gnat. Yep that looks like the answer then.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for finding that @gnat!

Comment: Wow, the title of the question this is a dupe of is rather undescriptive. No wonder I didn't find it while searching

Comment: that's why [Atwood loves duplicates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) - questions with better titles provide smoother way to find their dupe targets